# AngularJS templateUrl not loading templates in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-7

As per the title, when I use templateUrl inside of my $routeProvider, the template and controller do not load.

In my config, I have:

```
.when('/thing/:thingId', {
    templateUrl: 'views/things.html',
    controller: 'ThingController'
})
```

If I change that to

```
.when('/thing/:thingId', {
    template: '<div>Hello you!</div>',
    controller: 'ThingController'
})
```

It works. I'm using AngularJS 1.2.2.

Ideas I've tried:

1. I've tried adding the template to a script tag which still doesn't work. I get no errors and, since it's on IE, no debug messages. I've got an alert that fires the moment my controller is instantiated. This doesn't happen in IE 7 (and probably 8).
2. Added html5shiv, json3 shim, angular-ui's ie shiv, and I've created all the common document elements.
3. I've got the following at the top of my site:

   <html class="ng-app:ThingApp" ng-app="ThingApp" id="ng-app"  xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">

Each idea I've tried works in Chrome and IE10 emulating IE7 (the entire thing works in IE10 emulating IE7, just not real IE7).

I'll try to put up an example to demonstrate the problem but wanted to pose the question first.

**EDIT** In hindsight I've realized a plunkr example is silly because plunkr doesn't run in IE7 and this code works in things that DO run plunkr. Anyway, I created it so that code can be viewed.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yswo2QzcwfpzT2PXJV8m

Comment: Doesn't work in Plunker => Plunker built with Angular => hmmmm ;)

Comment: does angular docs site work in IE7?

Comment: No. That's probably not a good sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that AngularJS from 1.2 onward, does not support IE7. Fixed this issue by switching to AngularJS 1.1.5.

Answer (score 1):

For Angular versions 1.2+, you will need to inject `$sce` and wrap your `resourceUrl` with `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl('...')` for IE7 and below, giving you the following in your directive:

```
...
templateUrl: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('/Resource/That/YouTrust.html')
...
```

[reference](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/error/$sce/insecurl)

you may also need to monkey patch document.querySelector by doing something like the following (if you are using jQuery):

```
if (!document.querySelector)
{
    document.querySelector = function (selector)
    {
        return $(selector).get(0);
    };
}
```

otherwise angular will blow up here (from Angular source):

```
var active = !!(document.querySelector('[ng-csp]') ||
              document.querySelector('[data-ng-csp]'));
```

also ensure you are following the [Angular IE Compatibility Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie), specifically adding `id="ng-app"` and not using element directives.

Do all of this and IE7 *might* work ;)

**Edit:** fixing the reference URL

Comment: I found as soon as I started using ui-router with angular 1.2.27 i had to change to use $sce.trustAsResourceUrl for my directives to get IE7 to work.